# ROS can't find rospack

Tags: cmake, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**When trying to use cmake with this CMakeLists:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include(/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(calibration_cameras src/calibration.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
include_directories(/usr/include/opencv-2.3.1)
```

**I get this error in the CMake console:**

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake:24 (message):
  Couldn't find rospack.  Please run 'make' in $ROS_ROOT
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (include)
```

**Running cmake in ros root gave this error:**

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /core/rosbuild/rosconfig.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:35 (message):
  Neither shared nor static libraries are enabled.  Please set either
  ROS_BUILD_STATIC_LIBS or ROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to true.
```

**I have checked, and rosconfig.cmake is where it should be.  Any help appreciated.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29038/ros-can%27t-find-rospack/) by [commanchetruck](https://answers.ros.org/users/1901/commanchetruck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to me that you tried to hardcode your paths (line 2 for instance) to workaround the fact that your environment variables are not defined.

First, type "source /opt/ros/eletric/setup.bash" then remove the hard-coded paths (re-run roscreate-pkg somewhere to know how to revert your changes) and then run "make" into your package. It should work.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0